# boost concept check operator() overload

Tags: c++, boost, c++-concepts

```
template <typename T, typename C>
class CSVWriter{
    template <typename PrinterT>
    void write(std::ostream& stream, const PrinterT& printer){

    }
};
```

I want to check whether there exists at least two overloads `PrinterT::operator()(T*)` and `PrinterT::operator()(C*)` 
`PrinterT` may or may not inherit from `std::unary_function`
What concept Checking Classes I need to use here ?

*(I am not using C++11)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like that

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/concept/requires.hpp>
#include <boost/concept/usage.hpp>

template <class Type, class Param>
class has_operator_round_brackets_with_parameter
{
public:
    BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE(has_operator_round_brackets_with_parameter)
    {
        _t(_p);
    }

private:
    Type    _t;
    Param   _p;
};

struct X {};
struct Y {};

struct Test1
{
    void operator() (X*) const { }
};

struct Test2: public Test1
{
    void operator() (X*) const { }
    void operator() (Y*) const { }
};

template <class T, class C>
struct CSVWriter
{
    template <class PrinterT>
    BOOST_CONCEPT_REQUIRES(
        ((has_operator_round_brackets_with_parameter<PrinterT, T*>))
        ((has_operator_round_brackets_with_parameter<PrinterT, C*>)),
    (void)) write(std::ostream& stream, const PrinterT& printer)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    CSVWriter<X, Y> w;
    // w.write<Test1>(std::cout, Test1());  // FAIL
    w.write<Test2>(std::cout, Test2());     // OK
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't I use something like `std::unary_function` or something already in `boost` instead of writing my own `has_operator_round_brackets_with_parameter` ?

Comment: also I am getting compilation error ` error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token`

Comment: @NeelBasu: [No errors](http://liveworkspace.org/code/c9502e52898c7896945c527b96dc5c01)

Comment: @NeelBasu: I see no differences between 1.51 and 1.42 version on boost wiki. So, it should.

Comment: gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1)

Comment: Oh!I didn't include <boost/concept/requires.hpp>